# Invalid value of report parameter XXX in Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I face the following problem when try to render my report :

```
Invalid value of report parameter XXX
```

I add the parameters programatically like this :

```
protected void btn_generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AddParamToRep();
            rep_attend.Visible = true;
        }
```

---

```
  protected void AddParamToRep()
        {
            try
            {
                int campCode = 0;
                if (ddl_camps != null && ddl_camps.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl_camps.SelectedValue))
                    {
                        campCode = int.Parse(ddl_camps.SelectedValue);
                    }
                }

                rep_attend.ReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("camp_code", campCode));
                rep_attend.ReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("dep_code", int.Parse(rad_ddl_dep.SelectedValue)));
                rep_attend.ReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("dep_name", rad_ddl_dep.SelectedItem.Text));
                rep_attend.ReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("rep_type", int.Parse(rbl_type.SelectedValue)));
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
            }

        }
```

---

```
<telerik:ReportViewer ID="rep_attend" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="700px"
        Visible="false" ParametersAreaVisible="False" ShowPrintButton="False"> <typereportsource 
        typename="Reports.Det_HR_rep,Reports, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"></typereportsource>
</telerik:ReportViewer>
```

---

**Stack Details :**

> [Exception: Invalid value of report parameter 'camp_code'.]
>   [CancelProcessingException: An error has occurred while processing the
>   report. Processing canceled. Check the InnerException for more
>   information.] Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report.ValidateParameters()
>   +218 Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report.ProcessItem() +51 Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportItemBase.ProcessElement() +31
>   Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report.ProcessElement() +21
>   Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ProcessingElement.Process(DataMember
>   dataContext) +112
>   Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report.Process(DataItemState state,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean processItemActions, Boolean
>   documentMapEnabled) +97
>   Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(ReportSource
>   reportSource, IRenderingContext processingContext) +514
>   Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(ReportSource
>   reportSource, Hashtable deviceInfo, IRenderingContext
>   processingContext) +259
>   Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportRenderOperation.ProcessReport(ReportSource
>   reportSource, Hashtable deviceInfo, IRenderingContext
>   renderingContext) +308
>   Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportRenderOperation.PerformOperationOverride()
>   +159 Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportPageOperation.PerformOperationOverride()
>   +83 Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HandlerOperation.PerformOperation(HttpContext
>   context, ICacheManager cacheManager) +45
>   Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.BasicHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) +160
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +399 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +76

Comment: And the error literally says `XXX` or is that the name of the parameter? I mean that name would be **pretty useful** for debugging.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud :`camp_code` ,the name of the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from [this link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/invalid-value-of-report-parameter.aspx), your problem is:

> ... Namely, when a report enters in the processing stage, its value is validated against its validation properties. If one or more parameters do not have valid values, processing is aborted. Report Parameters define the following properties used to validate the supplied parameters' value:

**Type**

> Determines the type of the values that are acceptable. The allowed types are Boolean, DateTime, Integer ,Float ,String. The default parameter type is String.

**AllowNull**

> Determines if null (Nothing in VB.Net) is acceptable.

**AllowBlank**

> Applied only when the parameter is of type String. Determines if an empty string is acceptable.

Comment: Is `int.Parse("...")` differs from `Int32` ?

Comment: @just_name, nope, `int` is the alias for `Int32`.

Comment: I allow all fields to `null` so the exception is disappeared but the report is empty ?!!

Comment: although i debug the code ,and finding each param has a value

Comment: @just_name, that's going to be specific to the report now.

Comment: this problem appeared only with version 7 , when i downgrade to 6 ,it 's resolved !!!

Comment: @just_name, ah the joys of upgrading!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:** a parameter was missing (not the one mentioned in the error).

**Answer 2:** on another report, the problem was that there were two data sources, one of which was to offer a drop down list of choices for the main source's parameter. When the report is generated programmatically using reportProcessor.RenderReport method, the supplied parameter must appear in the list generated by the data source for the drop down list.

**Answer 3:** in the report designer, right click below the report and select Report Parameters. For each parameter, check it's type and restrictions.

**Answer 4:** For each data source in the report, check the type of each parameter, and check that the value is assigned in the value column.